# How can I add OPTGROUP to select statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I'm building a dropdown option via jQuery using the following:

```
var myOptions = {
    var1 : 'Road',
    var2 : 'Rail'
};

var mySelect = $('#q54');
    $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
        mySelect.append(
            $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
    );
});
```

Building the dropdown, no problem - I'm then trying to append `optgroup`options - I've tried adding in the following code to wrap the `optgroup` around the option but no joy.

```
var i = 1; // Addition
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    if(i == 1){
        $("#q54").append('<optgroup class="optgroups" label="Team">');
    }
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
    );
    if(i == 2){
        $("#q54").append('</optgroup>');
    }
});
```

The HTML output of the above is:

```
<optgroup class="optgroups" label="Team"></optgroup>
<option value="Road">Road</option>
```

The output should be:

```
<optgroup class="optgroups" label="Team">
    <option value="Road">Road</option>
</optgroup>
```

Any advice welcomed.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

Comment: `$("#q54").append('</optgroup>')` this is not correct, `append` does not work like concatenating html. when you do `$("#q54").append('<optgroup class="optgroups" label="Team">')`, the tag will be created as an object (think of it like a tag with closing also).

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan - makes sense - then I am even more stumped what to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering jQuery `append()` like the html string is the issue you are facing here.

```js
var myOptions = {
    var1 : 'Road',
    var2 : 'Rail'
};    
var i = 1; // Addition
var $group = $('<optgroup class="optgroups" label="Team">');
$("#q54").append($group);
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    $group.append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="q54"></select>
```

Another solution is to use `wrapAll()` like Pointy suggested.

```js
var myOptions = {
    var1 : 'Road',
    var2 : 'Rail'
};    
var i = 1; // Addition
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    $("#q54").append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text));
});
$("#q54").children().wrapAll('<optgroup class="optgroups" label="Team">');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="q54"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - really appreciated.  Trying to get my head around how this would work if both road and rail needed a `optgroup`.

Comment: Should have said, if Road and Rail needed 'seperate' optgroups.